# Spring data rest 2.6.10 : Find by embedded attributes value via Rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy, spring-data-rest

I have `Ruleset` entity with embedded attribute `ruleConfigurations` and am trying to get rulesets with active ruleconfigurations via Rest, below are my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ruleset")
class RuleSet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id

    @Nationalized
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean active

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Rule.class)    
    private Set<Rule> rules

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = RuleConfiguration.class) 
    private Set<RuleConfiguration> ruleConfigurations;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ruleconfiguration")
class RuleConfiguration implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id

    @Nationalized
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name

    @Nationalized
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @ColumnDefault("1")
    private boolean active

    @Nationalized
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String value
    //getters and setters
}
```

Below is my `RuleConfigurationRepository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "ruleConfigurations", path = "ruleConfigurations")
interface RuleConfigurationRepository extends CrudRepository<RuleConfiguration, Long> {
    List<RuleConfiguration> findByActive(@Param("active")Boolean active)
}
```

If am trying to find all the active `ruleConfigurations` via below rest api it works fine

```
https://localhost/api/ruleConfigurations/search/findByActive?active=1
```

But when am trying to find all the active `ruleConfigurations` for a specific `ruleset` via below rest api it throws `404` error

```
https://localhost/api/ruleSets/7/ruleConfigurations/search/findByActive?active=1
```

Can someone please help me to find by embedded attribute's specific value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can not do that out-of-the-box with spring data rest.

Try it with a custom handler. Below I leave an example that could work

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class RuleSetCustomController {

    private final RuleSetRespositry repository;

    @Autowired
    public RuleSetCustomController(RuleSetRespositry repo) { 
        this.repository = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/ruleSets/{ruleSetId}/ruleConfigurations/search/findByActive") 
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getProducers(@PathVariable Long ruleSetId, @RequestParam Boolean active) {
        RuleSet ruleSet = repository.findOne(ruleSetId);

        if(ruleSet == null) return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

        List<RuleConfiguration> resp = ruleSet.getRuleConfigurations().stream().filter(ruleConf -> ruleConf.isActive() == active).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Resources<RuleConfiguration> resources = new Resources<RuleConfiguration>(resp); 

        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources); 
    }

}
```

Link to the doc
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.x/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers